# Formate of DataFrame.keys() is not correct after DataFrame.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

***SOLVED:*** I was reading from the wrong source.

I have a DataFrame of a csv File which i read with Pandas.

Printing the **df.keys()** Shows me the correct format.

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv/df.csv')

print(df.keys())

Output:
Index(['days', 'day', 'n_total', ...,
       ...
       'foo', 'bar'],
      dtype='object', length=289)
```

After I use **df.drop()** the format of the keys is still correct.

But when i try to save it as csv and read it again with pandas the format is incorrect.

```
print(df.drop(df.columns[dropping], axis = 1).keys())

df.drop(df.columns[dropping], axis = 1).to_csv(r'csv/df_dropped.csv', index = None, header=True,  sep=',')

df = pd.read_csv('csv/df_dropped.csv')
print(df.keys())

Output:
Index(['days;day;n_total;...;foo;bar'], dtype='object')
```

So I looked at the documentation:

[Pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

[Pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

I was able to find that i can use **sep=';'** when to read the csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv/df_dropped.csv', sep=';')
```

My Question is, what am I doing wrong when I use **to_csv** even though i use **sep=','** when i save the csv.

Because the length as in the first Output is still not showing up after I use **sep=';'** in **read_csv**.

Comment: Are you trying to drop colunm names/labels or just dropping some columns?

Comment: I found the error, I had two subfolders which had similare names and I Always read the wrong csv which was saved without **sep=','**

But yeah I'm trying to split one big csv to 3 smaller csv.
I just drop all other columns with values and save the remaining DataFrame.

But I'm up for faster or better ways to do this.

Comment: Glad it's fixed. You may want to use an array to declare your drop columns: ```df.columns[dropping]``` -> ```columns=['someCol', ...]```

Comment: Why is this tagged with R? If you've found a solution, it's helpful for other users to post it as an answer instead of just mentioning it in the question (you can, in fact, answer your own question)

Comment: I thought R means 'read' but I understand now that it is the language **R**.

I edited the Question, but I'm unsure how I can self answere it - shouldn't I rather delete it since the Code is correct and I was just reading from the wrong source?

- Sorry for wasting your time, but it still kinda helped me to find the error after I wrote the Question.

Comment: I use a list which is generated with range, so I don't have to put in all the values by myself:
dropping = []
dropping.extend(range(day[0]+1, day[1]+1))
dropping.extend(range(day[2], k))